# SharePoint 2013 user login has changed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, authentication

Wondering if anyone can help please. I have an on premise SharePoint 2013 environment which users used to access using: "***DOMAIN\FirstName.LastName***" however the organisation recently made a change and users are now authenticating using "***FirstName.LastName@Domain.com***". Since this change users are being continuously prompted to login when accessing SharePoint via the browser or opening a document stored in SharePoint using office.

I have tried deleting the user profile service and completely recreating this however still no luck. Users are using a mix of IE and Chrome however I have checked all IE settings are set and also added the credentials to the credential managers, however still no luck.

Appreciate any help than can be provided.

Comment: Are you saying you switched from Windows Authentication to SAML or FBA? Or are users just using their UPN to login?

Comment: Users are still using their UPN, the default APN is what changed, this went from "domain.com" to "newdomain.com" and was bound to the users "domain\firstname.lastname"

Answer (score 1):

If you changed domains you will need to use the Move-SPUser command to migrate the SharePoint users / permissions to the new domain.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Hi Josh, 

The domain has not changed, just the default APN, for instance it has changed from:

"contoso.com" to "contosoengineering.com"

Comment: To give you a bit more information, when logging on to the site I am prompted for credentials in the format "joe.bloggs@contosoengineering.com"  however this fails, if I try to sign in as "contoso\joe.bloggs" then this works as expected and the site will authentication. However once I close the browser and login again I am asked to authenticate again.